# ERC20 Mint and Transfer Players

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, openzeppelin, smart-contract-wallets

I'm creating a game and I'm having a doubt about how I can work safely minting the coins.
Taking AxieInfinity as a basis, you play and win the SLP, at some point you can redeem the SLP for your wallet, my question is being in this process. How could I implement something like that?
I ask this because on the off-chain side (my database) I would have an X value of the currency that I could redeem, when my player redeems I need to take an amount from my ERC20 and transfer to him, the doubt is in this process , how to make ? and how to do it safely?

Does anyone have an example or something to guide me in this?

Comment: I already told you to use signatures https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/112578.

Comment: @Ismael I saw it and I'm grateful, but I'm still having a hard time understanding it, I'd like to see if anyone would have an example code for the real situation that I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm about to start this piece of code now, for now I'm finishing the deposit function, Token to (Virtual Token Game: Save Mysql). I recommend you do everything server-side.

what I'm reading you will need to get your private key and make the server-side code to make the transfer withdrawal automatically

Comment: Hi  @Mateus, Can you share an example code with me? I've been looking for an example for days and I can't find anything, this doubt is killing me little by little... hahahah what I need is when the player will convert the virtual currency (my bank) to the blockchain (mint the currency in his wallet)

Comment: I recommend that you don't mint coins, this is horrible for the game's economy.
It is better to transfer from a wallet that you are going to set aside for payments, to the wallet of the player who requested the withdrawal

Comment: Porra tu é brasileiro kkkkkkkkkkkkkk me chama no discord Mateuus#7601

Comment: But the question is there, how is this done? How to transfer automatically?